# How can I execute SELECT query without prompt dialog box in access?

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with a text box named fchName and subform of queryWorkerSub from a query named queryWorker which is "SELECT query". It needs a parameter.
I'd like to execute the query without prompt dialog box and with updating the sub form but I can't find way to do that. (I want queryWorker to be executed without prompt updating sub form)

```
Private Sub fchName_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim prmChName As DAO.Parameter
Dim dbs As Database, rst As Recordset
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("queryWorker")
qdf.Execute 'causes runtime error of 3065. Because of SELECT query
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges) 'does not update subform of queryWorkerSub 
Me.queryWorkerSub.Form.Requery' updates the sub form but shows prompt.
rst.Close
Set rst = NothingEnd
Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Your query obviously has some parameters you're not aware of. This usually happens when an expression in a field or criteria refers to a form or has a typo. You should examine (and proide us) the SQL statement of your query.

Comment: Open queryWorker in the query designer and look at the design, you will see what field(s) Access does not recognize and you can fix them. When the query engine doesn't recognize something in your query it pops up the dialog box so you can provide it.

Comment: @CPerkins I assume `queryWorker` is just a name of a query. If it's a plugin of some sorts, I don't have a clue what it does.

Comment: @JeungHunHan What do you mean with "execute a select query"? What's it supposed to do? As it isn't an action query, you can try to read information from it, or open it for viewing, but don't know what you mean with executing it.

Comment: @Patrick Honorez  I found I should have added "qdf.Parameters("paraChName").Value = Me.fchName.Value" just after Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("queryWorker").  But still prompting.

Comment: I should have added queryWorker. When I look at the query designer, , the query looks like "SELECT chName FROM Worker WHERE (((Worker.chName) Like "*" & [paraChName] & "*"));"

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth Yes you are right. queryWorker is just a name of a query of my own design.  "execute a select query" meant to executing query like "SELECT chName FROM Worker WHERE (((Worker.chName) Like "*" & [paraChName] & "*"));" sorry for making you confused.

Comment: I think you should just delete the row with the qdf.execute. That's for action queries. For your select, it's not valid, just drop it.

Comment: @Patrick Honorez I know that qdf.Execute is for action querries. What I meant is I want to know how I can run my query which needs paramters without prompt dialog box updating subform from the query.